# Why beautiful Stargazer cannot make text/html table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

R programming. Why stargazer cannot?

Let us do this:

```
oss<- data.frame('ESE' = c('CZZZZ', 'DDZZ', 'DFZZZ', 'FGDZZZZZ'), 'count' = c('1(~0%)', '1(~0%)', '1(~0%)', '1(~0%)'))
```

If we stargazer it we get

```
stargazer(oss, rownames = FALSE, summary=FALSE, type = 'text')

==============
ESE      count
--------------

CZZZZ     1(  
DDZZ      1(  
DFZZZ     1(  
FGDZZZZZ  1( 

--------------
```

It is not good. Continue then. Let us then fold dataframe:

```
oss1<- cbind(oss[1:2, 1:2], oss[3:4,1:2])
oss1


 ESE    count  ESE    count
 <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>

1   CZZZZ                   1(~0%)       DFZZZ        1(~0%)

2   DDZZ                    1(~0%)       FGDZZZZZ     1(~0%)
```

Then, after stargazering:

```
stargazer(oss1, rownames = FALSE, summary=FALSE, type = 'text')
```

we get a message:

> Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Please, who knows what is happening and how to overcome it using stargazer (or nor)

Comment: It works fine if you set `type = "latex"`